# Non scrollable textview in android

Tags: android, scroll, textview, autolink

I have a textview configured in my XML as below.

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <!-- more views here like ImageView and other TextView-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:autoLink="web|phone|email"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The content for this view could be text and may also contain HTML content. Hence I have set autoLink to true. The issue is, if either the autoLink or the `textIsSelectable` is true, then the textview starts to scroll similar to(MovementMethod) when its content is more than 4 lines. I am looking for a way to stop/disable this textview scrolling.

I tried to disable the scrolling using `setEnable(false)` for the text view, however, all the links in the textview could not be clicked thereafter.

I think there has to be a straight forward way to achieve "non-scrollable textview" which may contain HTML content in them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add the attribute `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to any View child. At least, I use `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` to make my TextViews scrollable. Hope this solves your problem.

BTW, why are you trying to display a clickable link when you can't even scroll to look at the entire link? Just asking out of curiosity.

Answer (score -2):

set ellipsize to the text view so text can't be greater than 4 lines

may be this is solution for you

Answer (score -2):

Try changing 'Relative Layout' to 'Table layout'... If this doesn't work then try to set appropriate padding and margin for Textview and other widgets.

Comment: changing layout dint work. the issue stays. neither setting padding helped.